# Array.prototype.forEach reassignment for the element

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I used `forEach` and it behaved somewhat differently then I remember. Normally I simply assign a new value for the element but it didn't work this time. Could it be that it doesn't behave normally in nested arrays?

Now for the snippet:

```
//works
this.array[0].forEach((ele,ind,arr)=>{           
            arr[ind] = 'E';   //works fine
        });

//fails
this.array[0].forEach((ele,ind,arr)=>{
            console.log(ele); //element is empty
            ele = 'E';
            console.log(ele); //element is 'E'
        });
```

I would assume that the element itself is copied by value instead by reference.

I read the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) but I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is strictly [pass/call/assign *by value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). That means if you do

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;
bar = 21;
```

then that will only change the value of `bar`, not `foo`. So while `ele = 'E';` changes the value of `ele`, it won't effect the array. That has always been the case and `forEach` works exactly the same for any array.

Comment: this is a very bold statement. It is not exactly by value. When the value is passed as a reference (as in case of array), then it does behave as pass by reference - if we change item, it propagates to the array. If we change the reference of the array though, it does behave as pass by value. It's a mess.

Comment: Don't confuse pass **by** reference with passing **a** reference. But you are right, with passing a reference we can achieve similar effects than if JavaScript had pass by reference. Still, JavaScript is strictly pass by value.

Comment: fair enough, however, in my understanding, pass by value would create a copy of the object / array, wouldn't pass a reference at all. From wiki that you linked

> that is, anything passed into a function call is unchanged in the caller's scope when the function returns

Comment: does it say in the specification that is strictly pass by value? I'm curious.

Comment: Pass by reference and pass by value only describe the relationship between *bindings*, completely independent of the value they are holding. You are right, a copy of the value is made. That also happens when you pass a reference. A copy of the *reference* is created, not the value it references.

Comment: The spec doesn't use the term, but if you read about how function calls and assignments are evaluated it's clear that is the strategy used. From Wikipedia: *"In call by value, the argument expression is evaluated, and the resulting value is bound to the corresponding variable in the function (frequently by copying the value into a new memory region)"* and that's what happens in JS.

Comment: To correct myself a little bit: We don't necessarily know whether a copy of the value is made, or not, that would depend on the actual implementation I guess. If we only deal with immutable values (such as primitive values and references (which could be implemented as immutable records)), then actually copying the value is not necessary.